# SQL days available using a not exists on current financial year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table called 'holiday table' which basically contains dates for all days where employees will not be in work (e.g bank holidays etc)

The below query is basically looking at the current financial year and working out how many days are available firstly by month, and then using the unuion all cummulatively, (e.g April-May, April-June) I dont need one for April though as I can use the non-cumulative for this.

See query:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, 
        @EndDate   DATETIME 

        --available days            
--current – start of this financial year
SELECT @StartDate = (select
case when month(getdate()) >= 4 then
convert(datetime, cast(year(getdate()) as varchar) + '-4-1')
else
convert(datetime, cast(year(getdate())-1 as varchar) + '-4-1')
end), 

--current – end of this financial year
       @EndDate = (select
case when month(getdate()) < 4 then
convert(datetime, cast(year(getdate()) as varchar) + '-3-31')
else
convert(datetime, cast(year(getdate())+1 as varchar) + '-3-31')
end) 


CREATE TABLE #data 
  ( 
     firstday    DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
     workingdays INT NOT NULL 
  ); 

WITH dayscte ([Date]) 
     AS (SELECT @StartDate 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT Dateadd(DAY, 1, [Date]) 
         FROM   dayscte 
         WHERE  [Date] <= @Enddate) 
INSERT INTO #data 
SELECT MIN([Date]), 
       COUNT(*) [Day] 


FROM   dayscte 
       LEFT JOIN dbo.Holiday_Table
         ON [Date] BETWEEN dbo.Holiday_Table.sch_cal_d AND dbo.Holiday_Table.sch_cal_ed 



where
NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT sch_id,sch_cal_d,sch_cal_ed FROM dbo.Holiday_Table WHERE 
    sch_id ='66291100Ks'
    AND
    [date] <= sch_cal_d  
    AND
    [date] >= sch_cal_ed  
    )
       AND Datename(weekday, [Date]) NOT IN ( 'Saturday', 'Sunday' ) 
GROUP  BY Datepart(MONTH, [Date]), 
          Datepart(YEAR, [Date]) 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 366) 

DECLARE @Date DATETIME 

SET @Date = (SELECT MIN(firstday) 
             FROM   #data) 

SELECT Period, 
       workingdays [Days_Available_Minus_Holidays] ,

       year (firstday) AS [Year]


FROM   (SELECT Datename(MONTH, firstday) [Period], 
               workingdays, 
               0                         [SortField], 
               firstday 
        FROM   #data 


       UNION 
        SELECT Datename(MONTH, @Date) + '-' + Datename(MONTH, firstday), 
               (SELECT SUM(workingdays) 
                FROM   #data b 
                WHERE  b.firstday <= a.firstday ) [WorkingDays], 
               1                                 [SortField], 
               firstday 
        FROM   #data a 
        WHERE  

        firstday > @Date) data 

ORDER  BY sortfield, 
          firstday 

DROP TABLE #data  

GO
```

The results for this are as follows:

```
Period  Days_Available_Minus_Holidays   Year
April                     19    2012
May                   22    2012
June                      19    2012
July                      22    2012
August           22 2012
September            20 2012
October          23 2012
November             22 2012
December             19 2012
January          23 2013
February             20 2013
March                     21    2013
April                      1    2013
April-May            41 2012
April-June           60 2012
April-July           82 2012
April-August             104    2012
April-September 124 2012
April-October            147    2012
April-November  169 2012
April-December  188 2012
April-January            211    2013
April-February           231    2013
April-March          252    2013
April-April          253    2013
```

My problem is when I get to the cumulative, it does another 'April' and then at the bottom it does an 'April-April' I do not need a cumulative for April as it is only one month do basically I dont want the first or last cumulative values as April is covered by the non-cumulatives, or if the second 'April' must stay, then it should not read '1' as days available, by be the same as the non-cumulative, which is 19 as this is how many days are actually available.

Comment: I think the second 'April' is actually part of the non-cumulatives and has gone over to 1 day past the end of current financial year which is why there is '1' day here and for April-April in the cumulative there is 1 extra day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the equals in your WITH clause

Change `WHERE  [Date] <= @Enddate` to `WHERE  [Date] < @Enddate`

It seems your adding a day to the date before the WHERE clause therefore it is overstepping by a day.